# Failover Settings for Oracle JDBC Driver

Tags: oracle, failover

Currently we are using and have configured Oracle using the JDBC Driver.

We configure the org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource bean.

But how can failover parameters like ONSConfiguration and FastConnectionFailover be configured?

Is this the right way?

```
<property name="connectionProperties" value="ONSConfiguration=adczatdb01:6200,adczatdb02:6200,slcc17adm01:6200,slcc17adm02:6200" />
```

Comment: https://keremerkan.net/posts/supporting-oracle-fcf-in-tomcat/

Comment: @Romain Hippeau.  Does that mean that those parameters can't be configured via bean settings  and require information in ons.config to be set?

Comment: You are going to need to play with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Universal Connection Pool (ucp.jar) to use Fast Connection Failover (FCF) along with the JDBC driver (ojdbc8.jar). Also, the UCP version that you are using is important too. Check out the [whitepaper](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/planned-unplanned-rlb-ucp-tomcat-2265175.pdf) for more details on how these connection properties are set. Also, check out [UCP developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjucp/toc.htm).